# Pyomo gives unknown "glpk" solver in python

Tags: python, pyomo

I get this error

```
PS C:\Users\oiste\Downloads>  & 'c:\Users\oiste\anaconda3\python.exe' 'c:\Users\oiste\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.2.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '55445' '--' 'c:\Users\oiste\Downloads\Assignment7_BaseCase.py' 
ERROR: Unknown IO type: python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\oiste\Downloads\Assignment7_BaseCase.py", line 140, in <module>
    results = opt.solve(model,tee=True) 
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\oiste\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\base\solvers.py", line 102, in solve
    self._solver_error('solve')
  File "c:\Users\oiste\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\base\solvers.py", line 119, in _solver_error
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Attempting to use an unavailable solver.

The SolverFactory was unable to create the solver "glpk"
and returned an UnknownSolver object.  This error is raised at the point
where the UnknownSolver object was used as if it were valid (by calling
method "solve").

The original solver was created with the following parameters:
        solver_io: python
        type: glpk
        _args: ()
        options: {}
```

with this code i got handed from teacher

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Jan 29 08:27:38 2020

@author: dqpinel

Renate Berge, 2021
"""

import pyomo.environ as pyo
import numpy as np
from pyomo.environ import ConcreteModel,Set,RangeSet,Param,Suffix,Reals,NonNegativeReals,NonPositiveReals,Binary,Objective,minimize,maximize,value
from pyomo.core import Constraint,Var,Block,ConstraintList
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory, SolverStatus, TerminationCondition



""" BASE CASE MODEL """

# Creation of a Concrete Model
model = pyo.ConcreteModel()


#------------------- PARAMETERS -------------------------------------

# Reservoir level limits [Mm^3]
Vstart = {'Upper':420, 'Lower':18}
Vmin = {'Upper':0, 'Lower':4}
Vmax = {'Upper':500, 'Lower':20}

# Discharge [m^3/s]
Qmin = {'Upper':2, 'Lower':4}
Qamax = {'Upper':12, 'Lower':12}
Qbmax = {'Upper':4, 'Lower':5}
Qcmax = {'Upper':100, 'Lower':0}

# Production [MW]
Pmin = {'Upper':12, 'Lower':6}
Pmax = {'Upper':200, 'Lower':200}

# Load [MW]
L = {1:60,2:120,3:90,4:80}

# Inflow [m^3/s]
Q = {'Upper':0.5, 'Lower':0.1}

# Constants and conversion factors
beta_a = {'Upper':6, 'Lower':1.5} # MW/m^3/s (conversion factor between production and discharge for generator 1 (Upper) and 2 (Lower), segment A)
beta_b = {'Upper':5, 'Lower':1.3} # MW/m^3/s (conversion factor between production and discharge for generator 1 and 2, segment B)


fm3 = 3600/1000000 # Conversion factor between m^3/s and Mm^3/hour. 1h = 3600s and M = 10^6.
l = 6              # Length of each time step (6 hours)
wv = {'Upper':650000, 'Lower':120000 }   # Water value for reservoir 2 given from the "Seasonal Model" to maintain long-term strategy (NOK/Mm^3)


#----------------------- SETS -------------------------------------

# Set of periods
model.periods = pyo.Set(initialize=[1,2,3,4]) 
model.periods_ = pyo.Set(initialize=[2,3,4])   

# Set of reservoirs            
model.reservoirs = pyo.Set(initialize=['Upper','Lower'])     


# -------------- VARIABLES AND THEIR BOUNDS ------------------------


# the variables are defined for each reservoir and each period

def qA_bounds(model,i,j):
    return (0,Qamax[i])
model.qA = pyo.Var(model.reservoirs,model.periods, bounds=qA_bounds) 

def qB_bounds(model,i,j):
    return (0,Qbmax[i])
model.qB = pyo.Var(model.reservoirs,model.periods, bounds=qB_bounds)

def qC_bounds(model,i,j):
    return (0,Qcmax[i])
model.qC = pyo.Var(model.reservoirs,model.periods, bounds=qC_bounds)

def q_bounds(model,i,j):
    return (Qmin[i],np.inf)
model.q = pyo.Var(model.reservoirs,model.periods, bounds=q_bounds)

def v_bounds(model,i,j):
    return (Vmin[i],Vmax[i])
model.v = pyo.Var(model.reservoirs,model.periods, bounds=v_bounds)

def p_bounds(model,i,j):
    return (Pmin[i],Pmax[i])
model.p = pyo.Var(model.reservoirs,model.periods, bounds=p_bounds)

# ----------------- CONSTRAINTS ------------------------

# Discharge
def disch_rule(model,i,j):
    return model.qA[i,j] + model.qB[i,j] + model.qC[i,j] + Qmin[i] == model.q[i,j]
model.disch_cons = pyo.Constraint(model.reservoirs,model.periods, rule=disch_rule)

# Production
def prod_rule(model,i,j):
    return model.qA[i,j]*beta_a[i] + model.qB[i,j]*beta_b[i] + Pmin[i] == model.p[i,j]
model.prod_cons = pyo.Constraint(model.reservoirs,model.periods, rule=prod_rule)

# Load Balance
def load_rule(model,j):
    return model.p['Upper',j] + model.p['Lower',j] == L[j]
model.load_cons = pyo.Constraint(model.periods, rule=load_rule)

# Reservoir Balance
def res_start_rule(model,i):
    if i=='Upper':
        return model.v[i,1] == Vstart[i] + Q[i]*fm3*l - model.q[i,1]*fm3*l
    elif i == 'Lower':
        return model.v[i,1] == Vstart[i] + Q[i]*fm3*l - model.q[i,1]*fm3*l + model.q['Upper',1]*fm3*l
model.res_start_cons = pyo.Constraint(model.reservoirs, rule=res_start_rule)

def res_rule(model,i,j):
    if i=='Upper':
        return model.v[i,j] == model.v[i,j-1] + Q[i]*fm3*l - model.q[i,j]*fm3*l
    elif i=='Lower':
        return model.v[i,j] == model.v[i,j-1] + Q[i]*fm3*l - model.q[i,j]*fm3*l + model.q['Upper',j]*fm3*l
model.res_cons = pyo.Constraint(model.reservoirs,model.periods_, rule=res_rule)


# -------------------- OBJECTIVE FUNCTION --------------------------------
    
def ObjRule(model):
    return sum(model.q[i,j]*wv[i]*fm3*l for i in model.reservoirs for j in model.periods)
model.obj= pyo.Objective(rule=ObjRule, sense=pyo.minimize)


# -------------- SOLVING THE SHORT TERM LP PROBLEM -----------------------

model.dual = pyo.Suffix(direction=pyo.Suffix.IMPORT)
opt = SolverFactory('glpk', solver_io="python") 
results = opt.solve(model,tee=True) 

print('\n')

for v in model.component_data_objects(pyo.Var):
  print('%s:   %s'%(str(v), v.value))
  
model.display()
model.dual.display()
```

So what is needed is the pyomo extension whcih i installed earlier via terminal, and which i have used previously. My problem here is that the code should be running, since it's a hand out, so it makes me think the pyomo extension is the problem, and i don't understand the error it gives. What are your thoughts on this?

So what is needed is the pyomo extension whcih i installed earlier via terminal, and which i have used previously. My problem here is that the code should be running, since it's a hand out, so it makes me think the pyomo extension is the problem, and i don't understand the error it gives. What are your thoughts on this?